# How I can add user reviews in my website like stars in play store?

Tags: html, web, user-experience, rating, review

I want to add stars in my website that users can use to add reviews in my website.
Like Play store shows stars for users to give rating. Have anyone have a way to do this.

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS, HTML5 and JavaScript or you can use specific libraries for it. Check how to design star rating with css [here](https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/)
And for javascript check it [here](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/)

Hope I helped

Answer (score 0):

Best way to implement is to use [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/) for showing star and half star
and handle clicking event on them by jquery or angular or ...

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete plugin named jquery bar rating with call back functionality

```js
   $(function() {
          $('#example').barrating({
            theme: 'fontawesome-stars-o',
            //readonly: true,
           // showSelectedRating:false
          });
       });
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-bar-rating/1.2.2/themes/fontawesome-stars-o.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery-bar-rating/1.2.2/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
<select id="example">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```